# Best way to run multiple COUNT/statistical statements in the same table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to gather some statistical information about staff. The below query will work to gather all the applicable information in the SELECT statement about a particular school in a particular district.

What I really like to do now is be able to run the SELECT Statement against different schools within the same district to compare schools within a district, or perhaps even compare districts to each other.

All of the data is, however, in one table. Obviously I can't put multiple statements in my query one after the other. I tried putting a `UNION JOIN` between but that didn't work either.

```
SELECT WorkLocationName AS District, SchoolName AS School, COUNT(FileNumber) AS Records,MIN(strftime('%Y', date('now')) - BirthYear) AS MinAge,MAX(strftime('%Y', date('now')) - BirthYear) AS MaxAge,
    AVG(strftime('%Y', date('now')) - BirthYear) AS AvgAge,
    (MIN(CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary,',',''),'$','') AS REAL))) As MinSalary,
    (MAX(CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary,',',''),'$','') AS REAL))) As MaxSalary,
    (AVG(CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary,',',''),'$','') AS REAL))) As AvgSalary
FROM DPISTAFF2015_2016
WHERE CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary,',',''),'$','') AS REAL) > 0.00
    AND WorkLocationName = 'XXX Sch Dist'
    AND SchoolName = 'XXX High'
```

I am wondering what the best course of action would be at this point. I can use `SELECT DISTINCT SchoolName` to get a unique listing of schools and use a WHERE to get only unique schools in a certain district, but how could I perform the SELECT statements I have (i.e. count records, max and min age, max and min salary, etc.) for each school or district?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `group by`:

```
SELECT WorkLocationName, SchoolName,
       COUNT(FileNumber) AS Records,
       MIN(strftime('%Y', date('now')) - BirthYear) AS MinAge,
       MAX(strftime('%Y', date('now')) - BirthYear) AS MaxAge,
       AVG(strftime('%Y', date('now')) - BirthYear) AS AvgAge,
       MIN(CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary, ',', ''), '$', '') AS REAL)) As MinSalary,
       MAX(CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary, ',', ''), '$', '') AS REAL)) As MaxSalary,
       AVG(CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary, ',', ''), '$', '') AS REAL)) As AvgSalary
FROM DPISTAFF2015_2016
WHERE CAST(replace(replace(TotSalary, ',', ''), '$', '') AS REAL) > 0.00
GROUP BY WorkLocationName, SchoolName;
```

You should fix your table so numbers are stored as numbers, not as strings.